# Search in SQL Server comma string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to perform a search in a SQL Server comma string.

For example :

The column `type` has values `"A, C, T"` and the user passes through an app the values `"M, T"`.

I need to return all rows containing at least `M`, `T`, or both. In this case, `A, C, T` must be returned.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Split your value first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) and then compare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to fix your data structure, with one `type` per row.  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column.

But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  You can use `like` to solve this:

```
where ', ' + type + ', ' like '%, M, %' or
      ', ' + type + ', ' like '%, T, %'
```

The trick here is to wrap commas round `type`, so that 'M' and 'T' will also be found when they are the start or end of `type`.

Comment: Thank you! It's a very old database and we can't change it's structure. I think the best solution would be a column by type but... :)